# Header e footer do bootgrid duplicados

Tags: bootgrid

Boa tarde!
Eu uso o `bootgrid` para montar uma tabela e um erro começou a ocorrer.

**Erro:** Assim que a tabela é carregada (do jeito correto, com barra de pesquisa e no footer temos a barra de navegação entre páginas), depois de um pequeno intervalo (nunca padronizado), as barras de pesquisa e de paginação são duplicadas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs.: A barra de paginação que aparece depois fica referente a quantidade de registro apresentados naquele momento, por isso sempre aparece com 1 página.

**Código:**

```
var html='<table id="grid-data" class="table table-hover table-striped tablerecords tabelas" >'+
                    '<thead>'+
                    '<tr>' +
                        '<th style="text-align:center;" scope="col" data-column-id="id" data-formatter="ident" data-sortable="false" data-header-align="center" data-visible="false">ID</th>'+
                        '<th  scope="col" data-column-id="dateStart" data-header-align="center">Date</th>'+
                        '<th  scope="col" data-column-id="StartTime" data-header-align="center"> Start time</th>'+
                        '<th  scope="col" data-column-id="endTime" data-header-align="center"> End Time</th>'+
                        '<th  scope="col" data-column-id="duration" data-header-align="center" data-visible="false"> Duration</th>'+
                        '<th  scope="col" data-column-id="callingParty" data-formatter="calling" data-header-align="center"> Calling Party</th>' +
                        '<th  scope="col" data-column-id="calledParty" data-formatter="called" data-header-align="center"> Called Party</th>'+
                        '<th  scope="col" data-column-id="direction" data-header-align="center">Direction</th>'+
                        '<th  scope="col" data-column-id="fullName" data-header-align="center"> Full Name</th>'+
                        '<th scope="col" data-column-id="businessData"> Business Data</th>'+
                        '<th  scope="col" data-column-id="path" data-formatter="commands" data-sortable="false" data-header-align="center"> Play</th>'+
                        '<th  scope="col" data-column-id="deviceType" data-header-align="center"> Device type</th>'+
                        '<th  scope="col" data-column-id="server" data-header-align="center" data-visible="false"> Server</th>'+
                        '</tr>'+
                        '</thead>'+
                        '<tbody>';

// Codigo que preenche dinamicamente as linhas da tabela

$331("#tabelas").append(html+htmlType+"</tbody></table>");//a variavel htmlType tem o corpo da tabela. o $331 eh a versao do Jquery que uso (como a página usa duaa versões diferentes, usei o jQuery.noConflict()

//montagem do bootgrid
var grid =$331("#grid-data").bootgrid({
                // labels:traducao,
                caseSensitive:false,
                formatters:{
                    "ident":function(column,row)
                    {
                        return "<abbr title='"+ row.id +"' onclick=\"copiarTexto('"+row.id+"');\"><i class='fas fa-id-card fa-2x'></i></abbr>"
                    },

                    "commands":function(column,row)
                    {
                        var path="";
                        if(row.path){
                            //var path= "\'"+"\\\\"+lista[i]["Path"]+"\'";
                            if(row.deviceType=="tipo1"){
                                path="\'"+"Server1\\Media\\"+row.path+"\'";
                            }
                            else if(row.deviceType=="tipo2"){
                                var path="\'"+"Server2\\sc\\"+row.path+"\'";
                            }
                            else if(row.deviceType=="tipo3"){
                                var caminho=row.path.split("\\")
                                var path="\'"+"Server3\\StorageCenter\\"+caminho[0]+"\\"+row.path+"\'";
                            }

                            path=findAndreplace(path,"\\","/");
                            path=findAndreplace(path," ","__");
                            //var _id=String(row.id);

                            return '<a href="javascript:playMusica('+path+',1)"><i class="fas fa-volume-up IconAudio"></i></a>';
                            //"javascript:playMusica('+path+',1)"
                        }
                        else{
                            return "<abbr title='Sem arquivo de áudio!' style='color:red;'><i class='fas fa-times iconeX'></i></abbr>";
                        }

                    },

                    "calling":function(column,row)
                    {
                        if (typeof(row.callingParty)==="undefined" ||row.callingParty=="undefined" ) return ("-");
                        else  return (row.callingParty);
                    },

                    "called":function(column,row)
                    {
                        if (typeof(row.calledParty)==="undefined" ||row.calledParty=="undefined" ) return ("-");
                        else  return (row.calledParty);
                    },
                }
            }).on("loaded.rs.jquery.bootgrid", function(){
                /* Executes after data is loaded and rendered */
                grid.find(".IconAudio").on("click", function(e)
                {                   
                    $331("#myModal").show();
                });
            });
        }
```

Comment: Para ajudar, poste o seu código.

Comment: tenta o datatable bootsrap, tem exemplos prontos

Comment: Código inserido. Eu acho que possa ser por causa das duas versões do jquery presente, mas as duas precisam realmente estarem na página.

Comment: Diego, por acaso você já implementou algum filtro por valor no bootgrid? parece que o desenvolvedor abandonou e tá meio difícil fazer isso

Comment: Leila, você se refere a um filtro pré-definido ao carregar o bootgrid ou o filtro padrão dele não está funcionando para ti?

Comment: Se for o primeiro caso, logo após carregar os dados no bootgrid (use o evento **loaded**) você pode usar o código: `$("#grid").bootgrid("search", "valor");`. Para mais informações tente ver na documentação oficial da ferramenta:[Documentacao](http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/Documentation#methods)